# loop inside a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am just starting learning Django and Python... It's been 2 months. 
I'm doing one of my own personal projects and i have a section where i am querying a webservice and passing back the result to the templates.

The webservice is returning a dictionary like below.

```
x =  {'ID':[{
    'key-1': 'First Name',
    'key-2': 'John'
},{
    'key-1': 'Last Name',
    'key-2': 'Doe'
},{
    'key-1': 'Age',
    'key-2': '25'
}]
```

I am expecting to iterate the list inside the dictionary and create my own dictionary like the below:

`d = {'First Name': 'John', 'Last Name': 'Doe', 'Age': '25' }`

I am not sure what am i missing, can someone please help me with learning how to build my dictionary?

Comment: Can you show what you have you tried so far and talk about the specific problems did you ran into?

Comment: I tried doing exactly what someone explained over here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289678/python-iterating-through-a-dictionary-with-list-values

But it's not the same that i am looking at ...

Comment: If your outer dict was named `x` just do `{el['key-1']: el['key-2'] for el in x['ID']}`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE] and update your question with the details.

Comment: @PaulRooney That worked!... Thanks a lot, It's a lot clear now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveat** be aware of ordering rules for `values` method for dictionaries.

Ordering rules [2.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and [3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

EDIT2:

To prevent any weirdness with dictionary ordering and the provided solution, wrap your data into an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

x = {'ID':[OrderedDict({
         'key-1': 'First Name',
         'key-2': 'John'
         }),OrderedDict({
         'key-1': 'Last Name',
         'key-2': 'Doe'
         }),OrderedDict({
         'key-1': 'Age',
         'key-2': '25'
        })]}
```

`dict()` is a nice option for something like this:

```
d = dict(each.values() for each in x['ID'])
```

output:

```
{'Age': '25', 'First Name': 'John', 'Last Name': 'Doe'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a dict comprehension and build a new dictionary with `key-1 as the  key and`key-2` as the value.

```
x = {'ID':[{
    'key-1': 'First Name',
    'key-2': 'John'
},{
    'key-1': 'Last Name',
    'key-2': 'Doe'
},{
    'key-1': 'Age',
    'key-2': '25'
}]}


print({el['key-1']: el['key-2'] for el in x['ID']})
```

Result

> {'Age': '25', 'First Name': 'John', 'Last Name': 'Doe'}